# How to get icons inside the input element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my icons to be inside the `input` element currently they all are mixed up together.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mochiy+Pop+P+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="container">
        <table id="mainForm">
          <div class="mainTable">
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label for="user" class="label">User</label>
              </th>
              <div class="icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
              </div>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="inp" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>

          <div class="mainTable">
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label for="address" class="label">Address</label>
              </th>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
              </div>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="inp" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>


          <div class="mainTable">
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
              </th>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
              </div>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="inp" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </table>

        <div id="mainBtn">
          <button id="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{
    background-color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
}

#mainContainer{
    background-color: rgb(242, 53, 53);
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgb(189, 189, 189);
    margin-top: 200px;
    
}

#mainBtn{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
}

.label{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block
    
    
}


.inp{
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 300px;
     
}

#btn{
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline:  none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

}

#mainForm{
    border-spacing: 0 0.8em;
    position: relative; 

}



.icon{
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is few things wrong, and also it's a very broad question as there is many ways to get the same outcome in CSS/HTML. first the label 'for' option should correspond to inputs 'id'. Your inputs have no IDs so either add them or remove 'for' from labels.

Also code that belongs together, should be together, there is no need to keep the icon outside the table cell.

Consider using pseudo element as an icon, on input element. Mark the input as position relative, add some padding at the front and use absolute positioning to move the pseudo element to required position.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to add icon inside the input using css. you can add icon as input background and set the padding or you can place icon beside the input and set position of the icon and make it look like inside the input using css.